# Navigationbar position reset when turn back to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

I set my navigation bar in my first ViewContoller at `viewWillAppear`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
```

It let me put a logo above the bar .

But when I turn the app to background and turn back , the navigationbar position reset to the top .

I have tried addObserver that catch`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and set the frame of navigationbar again . But it's not working .

Please help ,
thanks a lot .

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the solution.

1. Subclass UINavigationBar.
2. implement the `- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size` method to change navigation bar size.

such as

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = self.window.bounds.size ;
    newSize.height = 91;
    return newSize;
}
```

It works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to change the appearance of the `NavigationBar` and it will reflect allover the app

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:];
```

and you can change its background image if you want

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:];
```

Comment: I add it at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, self.window.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];`  . But the navigation bar no change.